# How to implement SaveFileDialog with my button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In my form I have this:

```
private void button_Click_C_Open(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {

                        filein = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                        fileout = "D://Download/Scuola/C++/Visual Studio/genericFileName.txt"; //crea un file e ci mette la roba criptata
                        textFileScelto.Text = filein;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

I would like to know two things that I have no idea how to do it ...

1. for the fileout, how do I bring up a SaveFileDialog instead of manually enter the location in the program (no: `fileout = "D: // downloads / School / C ++ / Visual Studio / genericFileName.txt"`)?
2. how can I make sure that the fileout is the same format of filein? (for example, if I select as a filein a file.exe, the fileout must already `.exe` and I will have to choose only the name).

Thanks in advance, I apologize for any grammatical mistakes.I hope I understand well your answers.

**Edit:**
I solved my first problem (.1) but now came out another:

```
private void button_Click_C_Open(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        //openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        filein = openFileDialog1.FileName; //file in lo scegliamo dal openfiledialog
                        textFileScelto.Text = filein; //visualizza la scelta in una textbox
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Encypt_File_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Stream my1Stream;
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if ((my1Stream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    fileout = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                    passwordBytes = GetPasswordBytes();
                    AES.EncryptFile(filein, fileout, passwordBytes);
                    MessageBox.Show("File Criptato!");
                    my1Stream.Close();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now, when I enter the name of the file to be saved, it gives me an error: the process cannot access the files (directory+name of fileout) Because it is being used by another process. :( Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) (used about the same way as OpenFileDialog)

2) Just setup the SaveFileDialog options to force the extension. You can also validate and/or force the extension yourself after the user exits the dialog.

Comment: Ty, but for the 2nd request, it's impossible to read the filein format and automatically save the fileout with the filein format?

Comment: You could use Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName) to get the selected file's extension and use that in your SaveFileDialog. Maybe I'm not getting what you're trying achieve here... Trying to open a file and save it in another new file while making sure the extension stays the same?

Comment: I understand, but now i have another problem (look edit)

Comment: Give me a concrete step-by-step example so I could give it a try on my side. Also, describe properly what you're trying to achieve here so that we may propose solutions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024531/openfiledialog-savefiledialog-errorthe-process-cannot-access-the-files-because I solved it here :)